# Rename files to drop a date stamp

Tags: bash, shell

I have files in an input directory. The file names are as given below

- SEMAPHOREINPUT_10-06-2015.xlsx
- WRAPPERINPUT_10-06-2015.xlsx

These files will be updated on daily basis so, tomorrow, the input would be

- SEMAPHOREINPUT_11-06-2015.xlsx
- WRAPPERINPUT_11-06-2015.xlsx

I need to rename these files to the filenames below:

- SEMAPHOREINPUT.xlsx
- WRAPPERINPUT.xlsx

I tried using the shell script below, but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | while read FILES

do

        newfile =  ${FILES/\SEMAPHOREINPUT_.*.xlsx/}

        mv $newfile /home/test

done
```

Comment: You are asking questions and always fail to present them in a decent way. You should go through [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three critical errors:

1. When assigning a value to a variable, there must not be spaces before and after the `=` sign.
2. Your string substitution is wrong.  To drop the date stamp portion of the filename, use

   ```
   ${FILES/_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/}
   ```

   … or better yet, since the pattern to be dropped must occur at the end of the string,

   ```
   ${FILES%_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx}.xlsx
   ```
3. You seem to have confused the initial and final filenames.

There are other problems as well:

- Parsing the output of `ls` is more complex and less reliable than a loop with a glob:

  ```
  for file in *; do
      …
  done
  ```

  Better yet, be explicit to avoid surprises:

  ```
  for file in SEMAPHOREINPUT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx
                WRAPPERINPUT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx; do
      mv "$file" "/home/test/${file%_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx}.xlsx"
  done
  ```

Comment: This would rename the file to SEMAPHOREINPUT. 

How can I retain format. ie. SEMAPHOREINPUT.xlsx

Comment: How can I extend this so that I place my shell script in a different directory.

Lets consider that the directory where input files is present is "/home/INP_SEM"

Comment: Change the glob to `/home/INP_SEM/*`, and strip out the directory portion of the path using `basename $file` or `${path%%*/}`.

Comment: I want to handle this file name 


SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_16-06-2015.xlsx





                                        

for file in SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx
do
    mv "$file" "/home/test/${file%_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9].xlsx}.xlsx"
done



But it is not converting.
I get below error mv: cannot stat `SEMAPHOREINPUT_NEW MID CHANGE REPORT_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xlsx': No such file or directory

Comment: The glob is failing to match the filename, so Bash falls back to interpreting `[0-9]` literally. The problem probably lies in quoting the spaces before and after `MID`. If you can't figure it out, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
for i in `ls *.xlsx`; 
do  n1=`echo $i|cut -d '_' -f1`;  
t=`echo $n1.xlsx`; 
 mv $i $t;  
mv $t /home/test; 
done
```